# Exclude Items from Another Table in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table that keeps track of links that each user has clicked and I have another table with links.  Here is each table structure:

**Links:**
id | link | value | date_added

**Clicked:**
user_id | link_id | date_clicked

Right now this is the code I am using to make my search happen and it works, I just want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing it, since the clicked links table is going to get very large very fast.

```
$history_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clicked_links WHERE user_id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$history_array = array();
while ($h = mysql_fetch_array($history_query)) {
    $history_array[] = $h['link_id'];
}
$clicked = implode(',', $history_array);

$link_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chip_links WHERE id NOT IN ($clicked) ORDER BY value DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($link_query)) {
    echo "<div id='claim{$r['id']}' style='text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; float: left; width: 183px;'>
    <a href='{$r['link']}' id='{$r['id']}' class='collect' target='_blank'>
    Claim {$r['value']} points!
    </a>
    </div>";
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial links.  I have been meaning to make the switch over but have had a full plate at my office and little time to learn.  This was actually the last site that I was going to pump out with the old functions before learning the new ones as it is a micro site that will only be active for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be more efficient to run a single query to get the resultset, rather than running separate queries.

You don't need to return all the `link_id` values, put them in an array, put the array into a string, and push that string into another query, and shuffle it back to the database... the database already has that.

This query will return a resultset equivalent to your current $link_query, without the need for the $history_query or $history_array.

```
SELECT l.id
     , l.link
     , l.value
  FROM chip_links l
 WHERE l.id NOT IN
       ( SELECT c.link_id
           FROM clicked_links c
          WHERE c.user_id = '$id'
            AND c.link_id IS NOT NULL
       )
 ORDER BY l.value DESC
```

If you don't have some sort of guarantee that link_id in the clicked_links table IS NOT NULL, you'll want to include a `link_id IS NOT NULL` predicate in that subquery, because the query won't return any rows if a link_id value is NULL. (This is a well-known and avoidable issue with `NOT IN (subquery)` constructs.

It's likely that MySQL will optimize that into a (hopefully more efficient but) equivalent NOT EXISTS correlated subquery, like this:

```
SELECT l.id
     , l.link
     , l.value
  FROM chip_links l
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1 
           FROM clicked_links c
          WHERE c.user_id = '$id'
           AND c.link_id = l.id
       )
 ORDER BY l.value DESC
```

For best performance, though, you probably want to use the anti-join pattern.

The LEFT JOIN operation basically looks for matching rows, and the `IS NOT NULL` predicate will throw out rows that match, so what you get back is rows from `chip_links` where there is no "matching" row from `clicked_links`.

The MySQL optimizer usually generates the most efficient plan with a query like this:

```
SELECT l.id
     , l.link
     , l.value
  FROM chip_links l
  LEFT
  JOIN clicked_links c
    ON c.link_id = l.id
   AND c.user_id = '$id'
 WHERE c.link_id IS NULL
 ORDER
    BY l.value DESC
```

For good performance on large sets, you'll also likely want indexes

```
... ON clicked_links (user_id, link_id)

... ON chip_links (value, id, link)
```

That should allow the query to be satisfied entirely from the indexes, and without the need for a sort operation.  The EXPLAIN output will include "Using index", and will not include "Using filesort").

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly for me and I learned a few new things in the process. I have never been much of a MySQL person, but it is starting to grow on me. :)

Comment: I did have one question however.  When you declare the `SELECT l.* FROM chip_links l`, what does the `l` represent in this statement?

Comment: The `l`, in that context, is a table alias. With that alias assigned to that table, I can qualify all references to columns in that table with that alias.. e.g. `l.value` means the `value` column from the table `chip_links`. The usage of table aliases has several advantages: makes a more complex statement easier to read and understand, column names that are keywords don't have to enclosed in backticks when qualified, qualifying columns avoids queries throwing "ambiguous column" exceptions (especially when new columns are added to tables); they are required on derived tables, etc.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I wish I could give you bonus rep for that answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this one-shot query that will tell you all links a given user hasn't clicked

```
SELECT l.* FROM chip_links l
LEFT JOIN clicked_links c ON (c.link_id=l.id AND l.user_id='$id')
WHERE c.link_id IS NULL
ORDER BY l.value DESC;
```

If you're not familiar with a left join, it will include rows from clicked_links where the join clause matches, but where we don't get a match, we'll just get nulls. Since we're interested in the non-matches, the WHERE clause ensures these are the only rows we'll get.

This would probably be more efficient that using two queries and some PHP code, but only a benchmark would tell you for sure. You should also examine the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to  ensure that a suitable index is being used.